# Storing Dropdown values in DB using cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, drop-down-menu

I have two tables:

1. contacts
2. phonetypes

In my add action, i populate a dropdown box from the `phonetypes` table (which has only 1 column, namely `phone_type`).

My `contacts` table has the fields: `l_name`, `f_name`, `phone_type` and `number`.

I have the dropdown's displayField as `phone_type`. Based on the selection in the dropdown I try to insert the `phone_types` field in the `contacts` table, but it inserts the id from the `phonetypes` table. But I want to insert the values and not the id...

Any help is appreciated.

My view code:

```
    echo $this->Form->create('Contact');
echo $this->Form->input('last_name', array('type'=>'text', 'size'=>10));
echo $this->Form->input('first_name');
echo $this->Form->select('phonetypes.phone_type',array('phone_type'=>'phone_type','options'=>$phone_type,'default'=>'phone_type'));
echo $this->Form->input('phone_number');
echo $this->Form->end('Save Entry');
```

Comment: It would help to see some of the code you are using. Try posting your Models and the add action you are referring to.

Comment: please add the code in your View where is the list of phonetypes, the problem may be there.

Comment: I have included my view code. Hope this helps in solving my simple problem

Answer (score 1):

The better question is, if you are not using an ID for the primary key in the phone types table, why even use the database, why not just use a static array? If you want to use the database, you should ad the ID column and store the ID in the contacts table that references the phone type. Then to get the drop data you would do the following:

```
$this->set('phone_types', $this->PhoneType->find('list));
```

Then in the view, the form field will look like:

```
echo $this->Form->input('phone_type', array('options'=> $phone_types));
```

If you do NOT want to use the ID in the table, then just eliminate the table and set up a static array:

```
$this->set('phone_types', array('Home' => 'Home', 'Cell' => 'Cell', 'Work' => 'Work'));
```